# create an array of class objects in c++

Tags: c++

Hi guys I want to make an array of class objects....so that I can keep on creating as many objects during runtime as and when required
I wrote the following code, but its giving me error:

```
class contact{
public:
    string name;//ALL CLASS VARIABLES ARE PUBLIC
    int phonenumber;
    string address;

    contact(){//Constructor
        name= NULL;
        phonenumber= NULL;
        address= NULL;
    }

    void input_contact_name(string s){//function to take contact name
        name=s;
    }
    void input_contact_number(int x){//function to take contact number
        phonenumber=x;
    }
    void input_contact_address(string add){//function to take contact address
        address=add;
    }
}

int main(){
    contact *d;
    d= new contact[200];
    string name,add;
    int choice;//Variable for switch statement
    int phno;
    static int i=0;//i is declared as a static int variable
    bool flag=false;
    cout<<"\tWelcome to the phone Directory\n";//Welcome Message
    cout<<"Select :\n1.Add New Contact\n2.Update Existing Contact\n3.Delete an Existing Entry\n4.Display All Contacts\n5.Search for a contact\n6.Exit PhoneBook\n\n\n";//Display all options
    cin>>choice;//Input Choice from user
    while(!flag){//While Loop Starts
        switch(choice){//Switch Loop Starts
        case 1:
            cout<<"\nEnter The Name\n";
            cin>>name;
            d[i]->name=name;
            cout<<"\nEnter the Phone Number\n";
            cin>>phno;
            d[i]->input_contact_number(phno);
            cout<<"\nEnter the address\n";
            cin>>add;
            d[i]->input_contact_address(add);
            i++;
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please can some one out figure out the reason??
Thanks in advance

Comment: here's the error, code has been indented

Comment: what is the error you are getting? have you considered using `std::vector`?

Comment: newpro.cpp: In constructor ‘contact::contact()’:
newpro.cpp:16: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ in ‘((contact*)this)->contact::name = 0’

newpro.cpp: At global scope:
newpro.cpp:7: error: new types may not be defined in a return type
newpro.cpp:7: note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of ‘contact’)
newpro.cpp:32: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘main’

Answer (score 6):

**Many** problems:

1. Missing semicolon on the closing brace of the class, as maverik noted
2. Use of `string` without `using namespace std;` or `using std::string;` (or `#include <string>` for that matter)
3. Ditto #2 for `cin` and `cout` (and `<iostream>`)
4. `d[i]->` is wrong; `d[i]` is a `contact&`, not a `contact*`, so use `.` instead of `->`
5. `name= NULL;` and `address= NULL;` are nonsensical -- `string` is not a pointer type, and already default-constructs to empty
6. `phonenumber= NULL;` is *technically* valid, but still 'wrong'

Also, good lord, use some whitespace in your code.

**EDIT** (in response to comment): Your constructor should look like:

```
contact() : phonenumber() { }
```

Comment: so what should assign these to in the constrictor?\

Comment: @Frustrated Coder : Edited to answer that.

Comment: phonenumber is a variable not a function

Comment: @Frustrated Coder : Yep, but that's not a function call, that's a constructor initialization list + *value-initialization*. But, if it makes more sense to you, `contact() : phonenumber(0) { }` is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You forget the `;`

```
class contact {
    ...
};  // <- ; is neccessary
```